# What's the best way to run PC games like RCT3 on a Mac?

Tags: pc, macos, rollercoaster-tycoon

OK, I've got a PC version of Rollercoaster Tycoon 3 on PC CD-ROM, but I've upgraded to a Mac (MacBook Pro OSX Snow Leopard specifically) and I want to re-install it.

I understand there are a number of options for running PC games/software on a Mac, such as Wine, VirtualBox or BootCamp.

I already have a Windows XP VM in VirtualBox, but that's slow enough without trying to run something like RCT3 in it.

I know there's a Mac port of RCT3 released, but I don't want to spend extra money when I already have a perfectly valid PC version already.

Comment: Bootcamp will definitely work and provide the best performance.

Comment: this question kinda belongs here but at the same time kind of not belong here.

Comment: Related question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17280/can-i-run-pc-steam-games-on-a-mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot Camp is your best option, especially because it is unlikely that RCT3 is going to be the only Windows game you decide to play.  Newer games will want access to all the hardware they can get, so giving that to them through a regular Windows installation on the MacBook is optimal.

The one and only drawback to Boot Camp is that you must reboot your computer in order to play the game, so it is not as quick as popping the CD in and starting the game.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid having to setup Boot Camp, but I agree that's probably the best way to allow the game to have native access to my hardware