# How do I get Steam Indie Games to run under Linux or even a Mac?

Tags: steam, macos, linux

I am interested in getting *Children of Morta* or similar games to run on Mac or Linux. They are pretty decent machines with dedicated AMD GFX cards.

How to emulate Windows for gaming or get such games to run which are natively NOT supported off Steam. Anybody had any success which such Steam Indie game titles?

Comment: The Linux part of your question has already been asked about here: [How do you get your Steam games to run on Ubuntu through Wine or something similar?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/16751/4797) and [Is it possible to play games that run off of Steam, on a Linux or Unix-based OS (other than Mac OSX)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49760/4797)

Comment: Related: [Windows Steam games on a Mac with WINE?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6608/4797) | [Switched Windows to Mac, do I have to buy Steam games again to play on Mac?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254287/4797)

Comment: _Children of Morta_ should run on proton => https://www.protondb.com/app/330020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the settings of Steam and enable Proton. This will allow you to download every game while on Liunx and launch them via Steam, which takes care of setting up Proton for it. See the official [documentation](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton) how to start. While this does not guarantee that every game runs flawlessly, I've had some great success running Windows only games with it.